# PHP error_log writes in one folder, not another

Tags: php, logging, error-log

I have a simple PHP script that writes errors to an error log file, and also prints part of the error to the screen.

I first developed it in my "sandbox" project inside Aptana Studio (but really, they're just directories) where it worked beautifully. However, when I copied it over to my "production project" (again, it's really just a different directory on the webserver), it no longer logs messages to the `errorlog.log` file. All permissions are the same, and in fact I made the script executable (it was not in the other directory), and gave the directory full permissions (chmod 777). The `errorlog.log` file already exists as an empty file and is writable, just as it was in the sandbox.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/* logerrors.inc.php - Prints a "formatted" error message which will be displayed 
 *    within a handler (i.e. the notification bar) on the front end and writes 
 *    the error to a text log.
 */
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');  // Required to avoid errors.

 define("LOG_LOCATION", "errorlog.log");         // The location of the log file

 function writeError($error_string, $technical_info_string = ""){
    $tech_log_entry = "";                        // We should only log techinical information 
                                                 //    if it's provided
    if($technical_info_string != ""){
        $tech_log_entry = "\n- Technical Info Provided: ". $technical_info_string;
    }

    // Writes a log entry with full details.
    error_log("[ERROR: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "]\n- Error Displayed: ". $error_string . 
                 $tech_log_entry ."\n\n",
                 3, LOG_LOCATION);

    echo "error: " . $error_string;              // Emits the $error_string as output
    exit();
 }

?>
```

Interestingly, the `echo` command at the bottom of the script is working just fine, so it's obviously not erroring out on the `error_log` function. It just isn't working.

Any thoughts as to where to look next or what else could be causing this?

Comment: Check the permissions on the file itself. The directory might be 0777, but the file could be more restricted.

Comment: Check to see that the file and directory are owned by the user running the PHP process.

Comment: Hi JamWaffles, the file was set to 0666 before (all read/write), just as it was in the other directory. I changed it to 0777 just for the hell of it, but alas, no change.

Comment: @Devin: Please post your code in your question (FTFY this time). It makes it easier to follow and you may receive better answers than when linking to it externally. :)

Comment: Have you turned on error_reporting? Any error/warning? What does `var_dump(realpath(LOG_LOCATION));` yield?

Comment: And they seem to be owned by the same user as PHP/Apache. At the least, it's listed the same as it is on the working directory. To give you some idea of how my directory tree is setup, as well as my ls -l output (FWIW): http://weathersourcepa.com/dirtree.txt

Comment: @netcoder: Gotcha, thanks for the fix! Now interestingly enough, `var_dump(realpath(LOG_LOCATION));` gave me: `string(44) "/var/www/html/myapps/rpm-viewer/errorlog.log"`, and, sure enough, it was writing errors just fine there! Now that's good because I actually wanted the errors to go to that folder, but it's kind of curious that it's writing to a file in that directory instead of in the directory that logerrors.inc.php is located in! (Guess that might just be how it works).

Comment: @Devin: It's because it is your *cwd* (current working directory). All relative file operations are relative to that directory. If you want the file to be relative to the script, you'd do `define('LOG_LOCATION', __DIR__.'/errorlog.log');`